# Android - Calling The Date In HR/MIN/SEC/MM/DD/YY Format

Tags: java, android, datetime

How can this be accomplished? I've searched quite a bit and I do not see how this can be done. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");
String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Almost perfect - except the year is 4 digits not 2 digits as I need it to be

Comment: my bad make it yy and you will get your answer. I will edit the code